# TypeError: 'function' object is unsubscriptable in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, typeerror, arrayaccess

I have an array of string objects, with color codes for plotting graphs, which looks like this: `colors = ["ob-", "or-", "oy-", "og-", "om-", "op-"]`

When i try to access it with a for loop (where its index is less than the array length) i get the following error message: TypeError: 'function' object is unsubscriptable

The accessing code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    l = plt.plot(data[0], data[i+1], colors[i], label='Iteration-' + str(i))
```

I printed the color before and everything seems fine, I tried to check this on previous posts there were many, but i couldnt find quite the right solution.

So what could it be the problem or solution to this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Always post the entire traceback. And what's `data`?

Comment: Can you please show the complete stack trace

Comment: Are you sure it is `colors` and not `data` that's causing the error? I would add print statements to the loop and see exactly what the value of those two variables are on each iteration.

Comment: sorry data is an array as well, but there is not the problem cause i tested like instead of adding colors[i] i added for example "ob-". 

Data array is a 2D int array its a bit long to put it here but some elements look like [0.0, 98, 97]... [1.0, 0.8, 0.9]

Comment: You've assumed that both `colors` and `data` have at least as many elements as `files`.

Comment: The length of files array is max 3-4, whereas the length of colors array is 6.

Comment: can you give a link to the complete code on Pastebin?

Comment: Sorry I found out so there were some imports and apparently there might some function with the name colors, thats why the error was popping up, so i just renamed the array and everything is fine.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the code you've provided that would produce the error you're receiving.  If you're certain that's the line that's throwing the exception my bet is that in your actual source file you've typed `str[i]` instead of `str(i)`.  Otherwise, you're going to have to provide more information / code.